# Excel VBA - View Hide specific rows depending on value in another row

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've been struggling to try and get anything to work and hoping someone might have an idea.

If C5 has a value I Need Rows 6, 106 and 107 to become visible. I then need it to check if C6 has a value and if so make the next row visible and so on until it reaches row 106.

This will all be run under a Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range).

I hope this makes sense any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Drew

Comment: so if the cell in column c gets a value unhide the row beneath it?

Answer (score 0):

This will unhide the three rows on C5 changing, then unhide the next row as C changes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Range("C5"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Rows(6).Hidden = Target.Value = ""
    Rows("106:107").Hidden = Target.Value = ""

End If
If Not Intersect(Range("C6:C105"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Rows(Target.Row + 1).Hidden = Target.Value = ""
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tried this but nothing happens?

Comment: are your rows already hidden?  Did you put the code in the worksheet code sheet?  This does not hide the rows but assumes that the rows are already hidden.

Comment: Thanks, stupid moment had put it under the wrong sheet. secondary question how can i make it if the cell is blank that it hides the row?

Comment: so if they delete the value it hides the row underneath, or do you want to iterate the column hiding all the rows that do not have  a value?

Comment: yes so if c6 is blank then hide row 7.
also if c5 is blank hide rows 6, 106 and 107.

Comment: see edit @Drew.